Recover Samsung J3 2016 user data from lock screen
I have a Samsung J3 2016 (without root, USB debugging not enabled and stock ROM if I remember correctly android 5.1.1.), I need my old WA for legal issues. I currently have the screen lock, but I don't remember the password.
I tried to access with ADB, but from recovery, I can only use ADB Sideload. I tried to install different versions of aromafm.zip from recovery, but J3 2016 gave me an error, so I abandoned this option too.
Any suggestions for me to recover user data?

You need the password.

Here are a few things you can try.

Samsung’s Find My Mobile: Once you have paired a Samsung account, you can use this feature to remotely unlock the phone.

MicroSD or Google Drive Backups: Check if your WhatsApp data is stored in MicroSD card or saved on Google Drive. You can restore it to another machine with the same account.

ADB Sideload: Since ADB Sideload is available, you can try flashing stock firmware or a custom recovery to bypass the lock, but that is a bit of a risky approach.

Data recovery specialists: If nothing works, choose professionals who work in data recovery.


